# Moving bundled css to a different directory changes URL prefix ../ to only /

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I am trying to set up my webpack config (*it's my first time with webpack*) for multi-paged website(***not SPA***). Everything till now is going well but url paths for elements in css is not pointing to the right destination.

I am using `extract-text-webpack-plugin` to create separate css bundles and `file-loader` to load the images.

The problem is when the build process completes, **the relative URL in the css such as `../assets/images/<hash>.png` changes to  `assets/images/<hash>.png`** and hence the image doesn't show up on the page. But, the other images placed in the html page via **img** tags load up with `assets/images/<hash>.png` as the source.

#### Hence, my question is

- **how can I preserve the relative path inside the css file?**

I really could use some help as its my first time with webpack and have spent quiet a few sleepless nights figuring out this much. :(

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin("css/[name].styles.min.css");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");

const entryPoints = require("./app");

module.exports = {
    entry: entryPoints,
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/dist"),
        filename: "js/[name].bundle.min.js",
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            presets: ["es2015"]
                        }
                    }
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: extractCSS.extract({
                    fallback: "style-loader",
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: "css-loader",
                            options: {
                                minimize: true,
                                sourceMap: true
                            }
                        },
                        "postcss-loader"
                    ]
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ["html-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|gif|jpg|png)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "file-loader",
                        options: {
                            outputPath: "assets/images/",
                            publicPath: "assets/images/"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        extractCSS,
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: "index.html",
            template: "src/index.html",
            chunks: ["index"]
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: "page2.html",
            template: "src/page2.html",
            chunks: ["page2"]
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"])
    ]
};
```

**My project structure is as follows:**

```
Project
|
|__ dist
|     |__ assets
|     |       |__images
|     |             |__ image1-hash
|     |             |__ image2-hash
|     |             |__ image3-hash
|     |
|     |__ css
|     |    |_ index.styles.min.css
|     |    |_ page2.styles.min.css
|     |
|     |__ js
|     |    |_ index.bundle.min.js
|     |    |_ page2.bundle.min.js
|     |
|     |__ index.html
|     |__ page2.html
|
|__ node_modules
|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, as workaround, replace

```
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin("css/[name].styles.min.css");
```

with

```
const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].styles.min.css");
```

---

**Final solution:**

```
        {
            test: /\.(svg|gif|jpg|png)$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: "file-loader",
                    options: {
                        outputPath: "assets/images/",
                        publicPath: "/assets/images/" // <- use absolute path
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: We need to run it through apache environment, then it will work.